# Does Wordpress have an import function for their export function?

Tags: wordpress

I just exported a Wordpress homepage bigger than 2mb. Is there a simple method to import it again. I would even pay money for this very simple plugin.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress have a native Import plugin. On your admin dashboard go to:
Tools > Import and under WordPress click the `Install Now` link.
This will install the `WordPress Importer` for free.

See here:
https://wordpress.org/support/article/importing-content/#wordpress

**EDIT (OP CLARIFIED THAT THE PROBLEM WAS THE LARGE FILE SIZE OF THE XML EXPORT):**

If a WordPress WXR file, an XML file exported from WordPress, is too large to import, there are several things you might try to overcome that limit.

*1. Edit `php.ini` (Some hosts may not allow this settings):*

```
memory_limit = 300M
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_execution_time = 600
```

`memory_limit`: Maximum amount of memory in bytes that a PHP script is allowed to allocate.

Note: `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`, and `post_max_size` must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`.

*2. Edit `.htaccess` (Some hosts may not allow this settings):*

```
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
```

*3. Edit `wp-config.php`*

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');
```

See also Increasing memory allocated to PHP.

*4. Increase the file upload size limit and/or file upload space limit:*

Login to wp-admin as an administrator.

In the Site Admin navigation box, click "Options"

Scroll down and change the settings for "Max upload file size" and/or "Blog upload space"

*5. GZip the file:*

On some hosting services, a gzipped file can be automatically expanded in the background, without WordPress ever knowing the difference. This can allow you to make the file small enough to be fit into the maximum upload size constraints.

On Windows, use 7Zip to create a gz archive out of the wxr file.

On Linux, use the gzip command line.

Make sure that the resulting file has the file extension of ".gz" before uploading it, as this is often necessary.

If this fails, then try another method instead:

*6. Break the WordPress WXR file into smaller pieces by separating the data between posts and pasting the header/footer into each file:*

6a. Always have the header

```
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="https://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="https://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>
<channel>
```

including all info like category, tags, etc to just before the first

6b. Always have the footer

```
</channel>
</rss>
```

6c. In between, add the posts start with end with and check to see whether the XML file you’re creating is less than or equal to 2MB. You’ll get the hang of it.

6d. As always, before importing the new XML’s, backup the database of the blog you are importing the XML files to and might as well export XML file of that blog as well for good measure.

*7. Try WXR Splitter Utilities:*

http://www.rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/ (Windows)

https://suhastech.com/wordpress-wxr-xmlfile-splitter-for-mac-os-x/ (Mac)

*8. If you got here:*

It might be easier to just use the WP Migrate DB Pro (paid) plugin (https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/). Despite the name, with an add-on it also imports media files.

**More Information can be found on the WordPress documentation:**
https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-working-with-wordpress/#how-do-i-import-a-wordpress-wxr-file-when-it-says-it-is-too-large-to-import

Comment: yes but it has a limit to 2MB and my homepage is bigger

Comment: sorry, that wasn't clear for me - please consider revising your question to clarify that the problem is the 2MB upload limit. I will shortly update my answer accordingly.